# Save data from datagridview back into SQL Server database with Entity Framework and C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, datagridview

I'm using Entity Framework to show the content of a SQL Server database in a  `datagridview`.

Nice and simple:

```
  ASH_ORDER_DBEntities objet = new ASH_ORDER_DBEntities();

  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
       dataGridView1.DataSource = objet.ASH_PROD_ORDERS.ToList();
  }
```

This works perfectly and gets the database and displays it.

How can I save any edits made to the data in the `datagridview` back into the database?

Comment: Please share your working for edit functionality

Comment: Define _back into the database_  please.

Comment: So you edit the data in the datagridview, then click a save button, and any changes are then saved.